# what is using SR=MS.Internal.PresentationCore.SR?

Tags: c#, .net, using-directives

I'm going through some ms source code and ran into the two using directives:

- sing SR=MS.Internal.PresentationCore.SR;
- using SRID=MS.Internal.PresentationCore.SRID;

Can't find anything using with Google or Bing. My first guess is that they are there to keep people from mindlessly reusing ms code. I ran into them reading the GlyphRun class source code. Namespace: System.Windows.Media

Comment: Are you asking what `SR` is or what a using alias is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SR` is a set auto-generated classes within the .Net Framework that contain localizable strings that may be loaded from satellite assemblies.

This is a special part of the .Net build process.

Comment: At the end of the two directives I get red underlines. So, I guess I have two problems. I don't know about an alias. This sounds simple. And how do I reference MS.Internal.PresentationCore.SR & .SRID?

Comment: You can't. These are internal types that are generated by the build system. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I was just trying to learn how GlyphRun works by running the code and stepping through it with the debugger.